# Copy files from remote to Jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I do have an issue trying to transfer files from a remote machine to my Jenkins workspace (different machine). I want to fetch those remote files to my Jenkins workspace, to be able to edit them within the Jenkins machine.

I already had a look on the "Publish over SSH" plugin, but this just do work from Jenkins to remote, but not the other way around. Or did I oversee anything?

I tried to implement it via shell scripts, but the connection is public-private key based and I really would like to have a clean solution within Jenkins.

Do anybody has got an idea, how to implement it properly?

If you need further information, please just ask and I will provide it as fast as possible.

Comment: Have you tried CURL/wget? You can then checkout [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/07/wget-curl)

Comment: Can you set the remote server up as a slave node? If so, you should be able to easily do this using the pipeline DSL 'stash' and 'unstash' steps, or the file operations plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved that problem already just by setting up a proper private-public-key connection and SSHing via script.

Due to the fact I was not allowed to change the Jenkins configuration and installing plugins at all, this seemed to be the most easy and clean solution.

Comment: I wish there was more information or links or examples on how exactly to do this.